# multilevel SSH connection with VTune Amplifier

Tags: ssh, intel, intel-vtune

How can I connect to multi-level remote host using Intel V-Tune Amplifier.

I have two host (Host1 and Host2). I can login to Host2 only via Host1 (as there are security involved to restrict direct connection to Host2).

Intel V-Tune Profiler provides a feature of remote connection using SSH.
[image: connectivity option]

we have the option to connect via SSH (password-less mode) to the primary host
(172.22.84.169)
[image]

I am able to connect to the host 172.22.84.169 (host1) from where I have to connect to (host2) where I don't find any option !

can anybody help ? (#Multilevel SSH connection)

Answer (score 1):

You can work around the firewall by using SSH's port forwarding, without opening doing anything that allows anyone *else* to directly forward traffic to the protected host.

Make one SSH login outside of VTune where you forward a port from a local port on your desktop to port 22 on host2 (with its internal address).

Then tell VTune to SSH to `localhost:123456` or whatever local port you chose in your SSH client.